# Using resources (strings) from different Module in xml

Tags: android, xml, wear-os

at the moment I have two apps. A Phone/Tablet-app and an Wear-app which works without the phone and it has the same logic as the Phone/Tablet app.

To make development easier I want to put them in one app so I don't have to change code twice. A help for using same code is "[Android Studio “mobile” and “wear” project modules, shared components location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505629/android-studio-mobile-and-wear-project-modules-shared-components-location)". If it is easier than in that link please report to me.

Now I want to know if it is possible to share also resources like Strings.

[image]

In my example I want to know if it is possible to reference in the activity_main.xml in the android:text to a String in the de.mcd.common - module instead of the hello_world in the resources files of the mobile-module and how.

I hope that I've pointed out my question clearly.

Thanks for help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Android Studio, building an Android Wear project, how can I include the same file in both modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35444035/in-android-studio-building-an-android-wear-project-how-can-i-include-the-same)

Comment: did u solved this?