# What are mobile and wear modules?

Tags: android, wear-os

The WearHttp library is a library for communicating with web content :

https://github.com/takahirom/WearHttp

To implement this it states :

```
In Mobile and Wear module build.gradle:
You must be implemented in both the Mobile and Wear

dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.kogitune:wear-http:0.0.5'
}
```

I have an application module and Wearable module.

Do these correspond to Mobile and Wear modules respectively ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, but according to their doc: yes, you need to add this dependency in build.gradle files for both mobile and wear modules.

Comment: Well, it is stated in this [docu](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html) that in creating a project for android wear you need to first add an Activity window, add a blank activity for mobile and second, add another Activity window, then add a blank activity for Wear. So to implement a file in both Mobile and Wear, you need to implement a common module that is shared between Mobile and Wear module. Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505629/android-studio-mobile-and-wear-project-modules-shared-components-location) to know more about it.